# openvino human pose estimation 0007

Tags: deep-learning, openvino, pose-estimation, efficientnet, movidius

I am working with openvinotoolkit and I am trying to inference the model human-pose-estimation-0007 and that works fine on neural stick 2.

Now I am looking for the original human-pose-estimation-0007 weights o repository (Multi-person 2D pose estimation network based on the EfficientHRNet approach.) from which the openvino weights are generated.

https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/open_model_zoo/tree/master/models/intel/human-pose-estimation-0007

Answer (score 1):

Here is the repository for human pose estimation in PyTorch.

https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch